# WAS Liberty : ClassNotFoundException : [Ljava.lang.String

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

We are migrating some projects from WAS 6 to WAS 8.5 and right now we're getting the following error :

```
[err] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:120)
```

The full error Stack looks like this :

```
[err] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:120)
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:108)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[err]   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:635)
[err]   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:422)
[err]   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:348)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2388)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception detected while initializing context : javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2388)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 1 more

[ERROR   ] An error occured while initializing MyFaces: null
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

we've tried with solutions to similar questions, like adding a `Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true`parameter but upgrading or updating the JDK/JRE or the WAS Version is not an option for us so we're stuck on this and we dont know enough about WAS to explore more solutions on our own

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the stack, to see who it is that's making the mis-formatted class load?

Comment: @Jarid Sorry, just added the full error stack

Comment: Ugh... the class load is coming out of your old Sun JSF reference implementation, and some googling suggests that's a known bug (although I can't find a specific number/link). Plus, the "allowArraySyntax" parameter was deprecated and may have been removed, and I think it was Oracle/Sun-specific besides. The best recommendation I have would be to either pick up a newer version of that JSF implementation or (if you're just using APIs and nothing specific to the impl) remove it altogether and rely on the JSF implementation included with Liberty.